# How to build a type generator class based on the input data type and container type(by template arguments)?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

There exists two basic data types in my tiny demo program, represented by the below classes:

```cpp
struct FloatDataTypeDescriptor {
  using dtype = float;
};
struct Uint8DataTypeDescriptor {
  using dtype = uint8_t;
  uint8_t zero_point_;
  float scale_;
};
```

Conceptually, the data type descriptor and data actual holder(might be `std::array`, `std::unique_ptr`, `std::vector`...) are tightly couple together, So i decided to use `std::pair` to represent the data chunk, like:

```cpp
using ChunkTypeA = std::pair<FloatDataTypeDescriptor, std::vector<FloatDataTypeDescriptor::dtype>>;
using ChunkTypeB = std::pair<Uint8DataTypeDescriptor, std::vector<Uint8DataTypeDescriptor::dtype>>;
using ChunkTypeC = std::pair<FloatDataTypeDescriptor, std::unique_ptr<FloatDataTypeDescriptor::dtype[]>;
// ...
```

This can work though, but writing such template alias all over the place is a little bit of tedious. So i've thought of using partial specialization to create a "type generator", produce the needed `std::pair<>` type by provided templates argument.

```cpp
// primary template
template <typename TypeDescriptor, template<typename, typename...> class Container, typename... ContainerArgs>
struct PairedTypeGenerator;

// partial specialization for std::vector
template <typename TypeDescriptor>
struct PairedTypeGenerator<TypeDescriptor, std::vector<typename TypeDescriptor::dtype>> {
  using type = std::pair<TypeDescriptor, std::vector<typename TypeDescriptor::dtype>>;
};
```

And use it like:

```cpp
using a = PairedTypeGenerator<Uint8TypeDescriptor, std::vector>::type;
```

I've tried to use variadic template pack in the template template parameter `Container`. Since some `Container` might need extra argument other than the data type(like `vector` Allocator / `unique_ptr` Deleter). It didn't work, clang tolds me:

```
<source>:21:53: error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template
struct PairedTypeGenerator<TypeDescriptor, std::vector<typename TypeDescriptor::dtype>> {
```

---

Thanks to @463035818_is_not_a_number liberal and great advice, i continue to add more specialization for `std::vector` / `std::unique_ptr` /  `std::array`

```cpp
template <typename TypeDescriptor>
struct PairedTypeGenerator<TypeDescriptor, std::vector> {
  using type = std::pair<TypeDescriptor, std::vector<typename TypeDescriptor::dtype>>;
};

template <typename TypeDescriptor>
struct PairedTypeGenerator<TypeDescriptor, std::unique_ptr> {
  using type = std::pair<TypeDescriptor, std::unique_ptr<typename TypeDescriptor::dtype[]>>;
};


template <typename TypeDescriptor, typename Deleter>
struct PairedTypeGenerator<TypeDescriptor, std::unique_ptr, Deleter> {
  using type = std::pair<TypeDescriptor, std::unique_ptr<typename TypeDescriptor::dtype[], Deleter>>;
};
```

So now i can support case that `std::unique_ptr` with custom Deleter, just use it as:

```cpp
using Ptr = EmbeddingPairedTypeGenerator<Uint8EmbeddingDataTypeDescriptor, std::unique_ptr, decltype(&std::free)>::type;
```

However, for `std::array`, things become much tricker, the `std::array` Container type need a non type template parameter, which cannot be matched by the parameter pack. I just want to use it by some syntax similar as:

```cpp
using Array = PairedTypeGenerator<Uint8DataTypeDescriptor, std::array, 512>;
```

Comment: Are [alias templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) of any help?

Comment: How could you construct a specialization for `struct PairedTypeGenerator<TypeDescriptor, std::unique_ptr, Deleter>` since your original template only accepts two parameters...

Comment: @Nimrod my fault, just updated the primary template to add variadic template arg

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<typename TypeDescriptor::dtype>` is not a template. Its a type. In the specialization you want to specialize for `std::vector` not for a particular instantiation of it. The error is due to the primary template expecting a template as second parameter rather than a type.

```
#include <vector>

struct FloatDataTypeDescriptor {
  using dtype = float;
};
struct Uint8TypeDescriptor {
  using dtype = unsigned;
};

// primary template
template <typename TypeDescriptor, template<typename, typename...> class Container>
struct PairedTypeGenerator;

// partial specialization for std::vector
template <typename TypeDescriptor>
struct PairedTypeGenerator<TypeDescriptor, std::vector> {
                                    //        ^^^------------------------
  using type = std::pair<TypeDescriptor, std::vector<typename TypeDescriptor::dtype>>;
};

using a = PairedTypeGenerator<Uint8TypeDescriptor, std::vector>::type;
```

However, you only need a single alias template, no specializations:

```
template <typename T,template <typename,typename...> class Container> 
using PairedType = std::pair<T,Container<typename T::dtype>>;

using a = PairedType<Uint8TypeDescriptor,std::vector>;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, i wonder if it can support case like ```std::array``` with custom size parameter or ```std::unique_ptr``` with custom Deleter?

Comment: @user8510613 ok for `std::unique_ptr` a specialization helps. Non type template arguments are a little trickier. Not sure if something changeed in recent standards

Comment: @user8510613 I was only adressing the error in your code. Perhaps clarify the question to make it clear that it should work also with unique ptr with custom deleter and with `std::array` (template template parameters with mixed type and non type parameters are a whole lot trickier, and you dont mention `std::array`). Maybe I'll come back later to this answer to make it more complete

Comment: Have been updated, FYI

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if you're willing to accept helpers/wrappers.

Here's my take on this:

```cpp
template <auto X> 
struct Constant { 
    static constexpr auto value = X; 
};

template <typename T, typename U>
using array_helper = std::array<T, U::value>;

// base
template <typename TypeDescriptor, template<typename, typename...> class Container, typename... Args>
struct PairedTypeGenerator {
  using type = std::pair<TypeDescriptor, Container<typename TypeDescriptor::dtype, Args...>>;
};

// std::array
template <typename TypeDescriptor, typename U>
struct PairedTypeGenerator<TypeDescriptor, array_helper, U> {
    using type = std::pair<TypeDescriptor, array_helper<typename TypeDescriptor::dtype, U>>;
};

using a = PairedTypeGenerator<Uint8TypeDescriptor, array_helper, Constant<3>>::type;
```

**Full example:**

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <memory>

struct FloatDataTypeDescriptor {
  using dtype = float;
};
struct Uint8TypeDescriptor {
  using dtype = unsigned;
};

template <auto X> 
struct Constant { 
    static constexpr auto value = X; 
};

template <typename T, typename U>
using array_helper = std::array<T, U::value>;

// base
template <typename TypeDescriptor, template<typename, typename...> class Container, typename... Args>
struct PairedTypeGenerator {
  using type = std::pair<TypeDescriptor, Container<typename TypeDescriptor::dtype, Args...>>;
};

// std::array
template <typename TypeDescriptor, typename U>
struct PairedTypeGenerator<TypeDescriptor, array_helper, U> {
    using type = std::pair<TypeDescriptor, array_helper<typename TypeDescriptor::dtype, U>>;
};

template <typename T>
class AllocNew : public std::allocator<T>
{};

template <typename T>
class Deleter : public std::default_delete<T>
{};

int main()
{
    using a = PairedTypeGenerator<Uint8TypeDescriptor, array_helper, Constant<3>>::type;

    using u = PairedTypeGenerator<Uint8TypeDescriptor, std::unique_ptr>::type;
    using u2 = PairedTypeGenerator<Uint8TypeDescriptor, std::unique_ptr, Deleter<unsigned>>::type;

    using v = PairedTypeGenerator<Uint8TypeDescriptor, std::vector>::type;
    using v2 = PairedTypeGenerator<Uint8TypeDescriptor, std::vector, AllocNew<unsigned>>::type;

    // array
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<a, std::pair<Uint8TypeDescriptor, std::array<unsigned, 3>>>);
    
    // vector
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<v, std::pair<Uint8TypeDescriptor, std::vector<unsigned>>>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<v2, std::pair<Uint8TypeDescriptor, std::vector<unsigned, AllocNew<unsigned>>>>);
    
    // unique_ptr
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<u, std::pair<Uint8TypeDescriptor, std::unique_ptr<unsigned>>>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<u2, std::pair<Uint8TypeDescriptor, std::unique_ptr<unsigned, Deleter<unsigned>>>>);
}
```

*clang1400 -std=c++17*

Comment: It is a nice way indeed, to wrap the value inside typed class, thank you